Poincaré recurrence and learning on a Riemannian manifold
$$
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\iS}{\mathring{S}}
$$
Consider this version of Poincaré recurrence theorem, that can be found in [1] and is often mentioned in research papers [2-5] about recurrence in the context of learning in games [6].
Theorem
If a flow preserves volume and has only bounded orbits then for each open set there exist orbits that intersect the set infinitely often.
Does this apply straightforwardly to a dynamical system on a Riemannian manifold, or does the statement need to be explicitely adapted / made more precise to a Riemannian scenario? More precisely, I am interested in the following setting. Let $S$ be the standard simplex in $\R^n$ and denote by $\iS$ its relative interior, that is an $(n-1)$-dimensional smooth manifold. As a subset of $\R^n$, $\iS$ is open and bounded.
Let $G$ be a Riemannian metric on the positive orthant of $\R^n$, and let $g$ be the corresponding Riemannian metric induced on $\iS$. Let $G$ be such that

the volume of $\iS$ with respect to $g$ is finite, i.e. $\text{Vol}_g(\iS) = \int_{\iS} \mu_g < \infty$ where $\mu_g$ denotes the volume form induced by $g$; and
$\iS$ is bounded as a metric space, namely there exists $r>0$ such that $d(x,y)<r$ for all $x, y$ in $\iS$, where $d$ is the distance induced by $g$.

An example of such metric is the Shahshahani metric [7], with components $G_{ij}(x) = \delta_{ij}/x_i$.
Let $X$ be a vector field on $\iS$, and let $\dot{x} = X(x)$ be the corresponding dynamical system on $\iS$. Assume that $X$ has zero $g$-divergence, i.e. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det{g}}} \partial_i \left( \sqrt{\det{g}} \,  X^i \right) = 0$; [edit] and that the flow of $X$ preserves $\iS$, i.e. $\Theta_t(x) \in \mathring{S}$ for all $t > 0$ and all $x \in \mathring{S}$.[end edit] In particular, the flow $\Theta_t: \iS \to \iS$ of $X$ on $\iS$ is volume-preserving, i.e. $\text{Vol}_g\left( \Theta_t(U) \right) = \text{Vol}_g\left( U \right)$ for every compact regular domain $U$ (whenever in the domain of $\Theta_t)$.
Does this suffice to affirm that, for almost every $x_0 \in \iS$, the integral curve of $X$ through $x_0$ returns arbitrarily close to $x_0$ infinitely often?

[1] L. Barreira, “Poincaré recurrence: old and new,” in XIVth International Congress on Mathematical Physics, WORLD SCIENTIFIC, 2006, pp. 415–422.
[2] G. Piliouras and J. S. Shamma, “Optimization Despite Chaos: Convex Relaxations to Complex Limit Sets via Poincaré Recurrence,” in Proceedings of the 2014  Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms (SODA), in Proceedings. , Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics, 2014, pp. 861–873. doi: 10.1137/1.9781611973402.64.
[3] V. Boone and G. Piliouras, “From Darwin to Poincar\’e and von Neumann: Recurrence and Cycles in Evolutionary and Algorithmic Game Theory.” arXiv, Oct. 03, 2019. Accessed: Apr. 23, 2024. [Online]. Available: http://arxiv.org/abs/1910.01334
[4] T. Mai, I. Panageas, W. Ratcliff, V. V. Vazirani, and P. Yunker, “Rock-Paper-Scissors, Differential Games and Biological Diversity.” arXiv, Oct. 30, 2017. doi: 10.48550/arXiv.1710.11249.
[5] P. Mertikopoulos, C. Papadimitriou, and G. Piliouras, “Cycles in Adversarial Regularized Learning,” in Proceedings of the 2018 Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms (SODA), in Proceedings. , Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics, 2018, pp. 2703–2717. doi: 10.1137/1.9781611975031.172.
[6] D. Fudenberg, F. Drew, D. K. Levine, and D. K. Levine, The theory of learning in games, vol. 2. MIT press, 1998.
[7] S. Shahshahani, A new mathematical framework for the study of linkage and selection. American Mathematical Soc., 1979.

It does not suffice to affirm what you ask.
The problem is that the flow need not have only bounded orbits.
For a counterexample take a flow obtained from translating along some direction with constant speed on $\mathbb R^n$: the flow preserves volume but no orbit returns close to itself.

Thanks. If I add the assumption that the flow of $X$ preserves $\mathring{S}$, i.e. $\Theta_t(x) \in \mathring{S}$ for all $t > 0$ and all $x \in \mathring{S}$, then the orbits are bounded (since $\mathring{S}$ is, with respect to the metric $g$), and this should be enough to have recurrence, right?

Then yes. -----
